# In what jurisdictions is there a “duty to assist“ others in distress?

Tags: any-jurisdiction, duty-of-care, good-samaritan, moral-duty

Apparently in the U.S. there is no duty to assist others, no matter how grave their plight.

In what jurisdictions is this not the case?

Comment: Several states have a duty to assist, which might only mean calling for police or emergency medical workers. Some states have laws that might be considered duty to assist, such as observed abuse of children. You might consider asking a more specific question.

Comment: See https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/92046/is-i-didnt-think-it-was-serious-usually-a-good-defence-against-duty-to-rescu, which has answers for various european countries, too.

Comment: This question is an unconstrained list question. Which answer would be best? Every answer can be equally right, assuming none creates a bundle-answer of **all** jurisdictions and even that might be incomplete.

Comment: Trish how is that different from any other [tag:any-jurisdiction] question?

Answer (score 5):

[united-states](/questions/tagged/united-states)

Vermont has a general duty to assist others. At least nine other U.S. states have such a duty only in specific circumstances, and almost all U.S. states have some duties to assist in specific circumstances that were recognized at common law.

There is a comparative survey of the laws of U.S. states (without a great deal of detail) and various countries  available [at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duty_to_rescue) which also summarizes some of the main common law duties to assist in particular circumstances. This article also notes the special duties of ships at sea to assist each other under the U.N. Convention on the Law of the Sea and under customary international law.

Comment: Was that the setting of the final Seinfeld?

Comment: @GeorgeWhite ??? (I know almost nothing about TV comedies.)

Comment: The Seinfeld crew was in a New England state in the penultimate episode. They made fun of someone in trouble (as they often did) and got locked up because they were in a rare jurisdiction with such a duty. In the last episode the prosecutor brings, as negative character witnesses, many people in trouble who they laughed at  over the years. When I saw your answer I assumed they set in the only jurisdiction with a duty to assist. I googled it and it was set in a small fictional town in MA. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Finale_(Seinfeld)

Answer (score 4):

[germany](/questions/tagged/germany)

[§323g STGB](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/stgb/__323c.html) requires assistance in case of *accidents or generic danger,* but this is qualified by being *reasonable* in view of the conditions, notably self-protection and other legal obligations one cannot ignore.

For practical purposes, the requirement can be fulfilled by phoning the emergency services from the *next safe place*. Precedents were set before mobile phones became common, the usual example is a motorist stopping at the next open, lighted gas station and asking for a phone. And the *other obligation* would cover e.g. a pedestrian with a toddler along (who can't be left alone while the adult helps).

Answer (score 1):

From an in a publication called The Log -

> In the United States, federal law ([46 USCS sec. 2304](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/46/2304)) requires the master of any vessel subject to U.S. jurisdiction to “render assistance to any individual found at sea in danger of being lost,” so long as the assistance can be rendered without endangering the rescuing vessel or individuals on board. This law is a part of an international treaty (the International Convention on Salvage, 1989) which extends the obligation to mariners throughout the world.

> California has a similar maritime assistance statute, ([Harbors and Navigation Cod sec. 656](https://codes.findlaw.com/ca/harbors-and-navigation-code/hnc-sect-656/)), which requires “the operator of a vessel involved in a collision, accident, or other casualty” to render assistance, so long as the operator “can do so without serious danger to his or her own vessel, crew, and passengers.” A careful comparison between these laws reveals a different approach between California and federal law. The California statute imposes the obligation on a vessel operator “involved” in an incident, whereas the federal and international provisions apply to all vessel operators.

Answer (score 1):

### [Australia](https://www.anzcor.org/assets/anzcor-guidelines/anzcor-guidance-statement-10-5-1-legal-issues-related-to-responding-to-emergency-situations-and-resuscitation-326.pdf)

[australia](/questions/tagged/australia), with the exception of the [northern-territory](/questions/tagged/northern-territory), has no general duty to assist.

All jurisdictions have Good Samaritan laws that shield those who do assist from liability - no bystander or volunteer has ever been successfully sued for negligently rendered assistance.

Answer (score 0):

[law-of-the-sea](/questions/tagged/law-of-the-sea)

Duty to render assistance, Article 98, United Nations Convention on the Law of the Sea (UNCLOS):

1. Every State shall require the master of a ship flying its flag, in so far
   as he can do so without serious danger to the ship, the crew or the passengers:

(a) to render assistance to any person found at sea in danger of
being lost;

(b) to proceed with all possible speed to the rescue of persons in
distress, if informed of their need of assistance, in so far as such
action may reasonably be expected of him;

(c) after a collision, to render assistance to the other ship, its crew
and its passengers and, where possible, to inform the other ship
of the name of his own ship, its port of registry and the nearest
port at which it will call.

2. Every coastal State shall promote the establishment, operation and
   maintenance of an adequate and effective search and rescue service regarding
   safety on and over the sea and, where circumstances so require, by way of
   mutual regional arrangements cooperate with neighbouring States for this
   purpose.